# How do I make the block editor use https by default?

Tags: block-editor, urls, https, http

By default the Gutenberg block editor uses `http://` instead of `https://` when you enter a URL that does not include the protocol. For example, if I enter `stackoverflow.com` the block editor assumes it is 'http://stackoverflow.com`.

Is there a way to make the block editor default to using `https://` by default?

Comment: Could you provide more information, where exactly block editor uses http?

Comment: terryoboy was referring to the input for adding urls in button block, linking text to a url and in image blocks ; there is an outstanding request for this at https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/46244 ;  there's some previous work done for this at https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/47311 and https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/47312

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it sits, it looks like the comment from @Will means there is not a way to do this currently.

> ...there is an outstanding request for this at github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/46244 ; there's some previous work done for this at github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/47311 and github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/47312